# Have there ever been malicious MacPorts portfiles?

Tags: macports, open-source, malware

Is there a reason to use caution when installing packages from Macports?

I'm still new to *nix land, more a result of projects like Ubuntu making things like installing programs easy. I always felt confused and lost trying to compile programs, so  package managers like Aptitude are wonderful and magical inventions to me. And it never occurred to me to question the integrity of a package. I assume there's a real team of humans policing a given repository somewhere.

So when I discovered MacPorts, I equated it to Aptitude and was pretty excited it existed. But I'm wondering how well trusted it is, or if trust is built in to how the project works?

Has there ever been an evil MacPorts portfile?

Comment: Just so you know, there's also [homebrew](http://www.brew.sh), which is considered better by a lot (not exactly that relevant, but still).

Comment: @Fingebimus thanks, didn't know I found the lesser option. Hopefully the answer will apply to home brew as well.